# Windows Phone 7 and MP4

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-media-player

I installed all the needed tools and I wrote a simple YouTube downloader for WP7.
The problem is with playing.. I tried several mp4 formats (listed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs) with that code:

```
    new MediaPlayerLauncher() {
        Media = new Uri("http://localhost/asd.mp4"),
        Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All
    }.Show();
```

But every time it says "Playback error".
I've read the WP7 codec support page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28VS.92%29.aspx) and it has multiple mp4+aac supports.

Question 1: Can WP7 run YouTube videos (formats from the first url)?

Question 2: Will Microsoft accept my app for the Marketplace?

Comment: is it possible to record MP4 audio using WP7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will play mp4 (there is a youtube app in the marketplace), but the emulator will only play wmv files.  You have to test the other formats on a device. Don't know if your app will get certified ... check the [certification requirements](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730558) (PDF) for video specific sections.

Comment: @JP is the emulator only supporting WMV files documented anywhere?

Comment: As far as I know, the files should play on the emulator - sound should be playing and video running with black screen. Not "Playback error". I can't find anywhere what that error message means

Comment: @Matt Lacey:  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(VS.92).aspx on each codec it will say in the first column of the table whether it is supported in the emulator.

Comment: @Matt I'm pretty sure it's new .. but I may have just blocked it out as well :)